# LC3 assembly: How to add string to row of memory, not character

Tags: assembly, lc3

```
.ORIG x3000
LEA R0, SENTENCE_PTR ; start at memory address x4000 (sentence)
LDR R1, R0, #0 ; ASCII at x4000 ;                    (ASCII)
LEA R2, WORDS  ; start at beginning of memory block

STR R1, R2 ; store ASCII in memory
ADD R2, R2, #1 ; increment memory pointer


HALT

SENTENCE_PTR    .FILL x4000 ; beggining of sentence
WORDS .BLKW #198 ; pointers to words and counters
.END
```

I am trying to put a string of characters or word into a single row of memory. If I am adding one character at a time how do I add the character to the same row of memory to create a string. Can I add the entire string at once to one row of memory? I can only find reference material where a character is added to memory, not a string.

Comment: What do you mean "row" of memory?  Memory is essentially a 1-d array, not 2-d with rows and columns.  If you mean a single 8-bit memory cell, obviously that's only large enough for one character.  You could store a pointer to a string into a word in memory, if you want an array of pointers (e.g. `char *argv[]`).  If you mean copy a whole string with one instruction to multiple bytes in memory: no, this is assembly language.  LC3 doesn't have any machine instructions to copy more than one (or maybe 2) bytes at once.

Answer (score 1):

The standard LC-3 is word addressable, not byte addressable.  (There is an LC-3b that is byte addressable, but that is a fully different processor.)

The word size on LC-3 is 16-bits, and thus, it can support 2 ascii bytes per word.  Doing this is called packing: when we put two or more pieces of information into the same address.  Packing is not always done; sometimes one byte is stored per address (using the low order byte of each word) — so you should check to make sure that packing multiple bytes into one word is desired.

In order to pack, you have to consider that you (1) have a notion of the byte address you want, (2) convert from byte addresses to word addresses, (3) place the byte of interest into either the upper part or lower part of the word address.

This can be done generically if you create a notion of byte address, or it can be done with a small state machine in a subroutine, for example.

The problem with the former is addressing all of memory, since a byte address takes one more bit than a word address, so you would either have to use 2 words for an address or forgo half the address space in representing a byte address in only one word (16-bits).  However, you can create a subroutine that will store a byte at any byte address following the above.  It will have to read the word at the word address, replace the upper or lower byte (as dictated by even or odd byte address), and then store the word back to the word address.

For the latter approach, we might create routines for `strcpy` and `strcmp`: these would take word addresses assuming that the start of string is word aligned, then each such routine would have two sections (two states encoded in the code).  The first section would work with the upper byte from the word address, and copy or compare that, and the second section would work with the lower byte from the word address, and copy or compare that.  (Or lower first, then upper, that the question of endian-ness, big vs. little.)

(Of course, if we always pack strings into full words (2 bytes per word) and also ensure a string always starts at a full word boundary, a strcpy or strcmp can copy or compare based on words instead of byte by byte, ending copy/compare when the low byte is a null.)

`strcat` and some other string operations are a bit harder in that we need to maintain upper vs. lower state independently for both destination string and source string (whereas with `strcpy` and `strcmp` — given strings that start word aligned — the upper/lower stays in lock step across the two strings).